# emmeans error with glmer - variable not recognised in reference grid

Tags: r, emmeans

I'm having trouble using emmeans with a glmer object. I have an ordinal response that doesn't satisfy the proportional odds assumption and I thought to produce a binary model at each cut point as an alternative approach. I ultimately want to plot the predicted probabilities (for the variable combination) for being in each level of the response ([related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51033497/interpretation-of-emmeans-for-clmm-mixed-effects-ordinal-object)).

If I run:

```
# Final clmm model
summary(mmod <- clmm(sc ~ visit + group + lang + (1|id), data = dat, nAGQ = 10))
# Emmeans
mmod_em <- emmeans(mmod, ~ sc + visit + group + lang, mode = "prob")
```

This works perfectly. But if I then try one of the reduced binary models, emmeans doesn't recognise the dependent variable:

```
# Final glmer models
summary(mmod_2 <- glmer(sc_2 ~ visit + group + lang + (1|id), data = dat, family = "binomial", nAGQ = 10))
# Emmeans
mmod_2_em <- emmeans(mmod_2, ~ sc_2 + visit + group + lang)

Error in emmeans(mmod_2, ~sc_2 + visit + group +  : 
No variable named sc_2 in the reference grid
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This kind of sounds to me like a job for making predictions via `predict()` with `re.form = NA` rather than a job for the emmeans package.  Alternatively, if these are continuous variables you might [want the "at" argument](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html#numeric).  Also, folks will be able to help you better if you include an example of your dataset.

Comment: As I think about this more it's redundant to plot predicted probs for the binary case because one is just the difference between 1 and the other (i.e. P(y = 1) = 1 - P(y = 0)). I'm still curious why emmeans gives me an error with glmer and not with clmm though (perhaps coded that way).

Comment: You still need `mode = “prob”`.

Comment: Thanks rvl. mode = "prob" doesn't seem to work (for glmer?), whereas type = "response" gives me the desired probabilities